# Unable to run controller while using chi middleware in golang

Tags: go, middleware, go-chi

I am writing a middleware function in golang `net/http` using chi but the controller function isn't being executed (couldn't print 1 in the function).

Calling the middleware:

```golang
r.With(myMiddleware.Authware).Post("/tryon", mainController.Tryon)
```

package - myMiddleware

```golang
func Authware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Middleware code
    })
}
```

package - mainController

```golang
func Tryon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Dosent print anything
    log.Println(1)
}
```

I read the documentation but it didn't help much

Could you please help out debug and let me know why is this happening? Also, if I want to return some data from the middleware to the controller, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.go

```
func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.With(middle.Authware).Post("/tryon", controller.Tryon)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}
```

Invoke the `controller` after passing the `middleware` logic:

middleware.go

```
func Authware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Middleware code
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

controller.go

```
func Tryon(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Doesn't print anything
    log.Println(1)
}
```

If you really want it to be a `POST` request: `curl -X POST localhost:3000/tryon`

P.S: go through the code example here: https://github.com/go-chi/chi